# Replacing 'True & 'False' on chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making some graphs and wondering how I can replace 'True' and 'False' with other names?

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,7)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.countplot(df['Weekend'], palette='pastel')
plt.title('Revenue (Purchase/No Purchase', fontsize=30/2)
plt.xlabel('Revenue or Not', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('count', fontsize=10)

#chcecking distributions of customers on Weekend
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.countplot(df['Weekend'], palette='inferno')
plt.title('Purchase on Weekends', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Weekend or Not', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('count', fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

[graphs]

[image: 1]

Comment: please provide a minimal input dataset

Comment: `sns.countplot(x=df['Weekend'].replace({False: "Workday", True: "Weekend"}))`